# How do I populate a ListView with data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview, firebase

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
    players.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot player : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("player", player.getKey());
                friends.add(player.getKey());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    while (friends.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        // link between a set of data and the AdapterView that displays the data
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                friends);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I expected that it would make the current thread wait until Firebase's thread acquires all the data and stores it into friends array list, but I only get black screen on my Android emulator.
Could anyone give any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this task?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000);` line causing issue. why not adding adapter to ListView inside `onDataChange ` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `Thread.sleep(1000);` is blocking the UI thread. You should never do that. Instead, you should create the adapter and add it to the list inside the `onDataChange` callback. Something like this:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
final ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
players.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot player : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("player", player.getKey());
            friends.add(player.getKey());
        }
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            friends);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now it won't let me compile saying: Error:(50, 49) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous ValueEventListener>,int,ArrayList<String>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,Object[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: @romikps I've edited my answer to address that. You should replace `MainActivity` with your activity's class name.

Comment: In the `OnDataChange()` put `ArrayAdapter` code outside the `for loop`.....bcoz its intialize again and agian ..........

Comment: @sushildlh I've fixed that, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: i was just wondering, if I want the data stored at the reference, shouldn't I use the getValue() method?

Comment: @YashChowdhary I've used `getKey()` because that is what the OP used in his question. If you need the value, you should use `getValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

Bcoz of **firebase response** take some time, so other **code run before you getting data** and then you get **firebase response**.So good idea is put your code inside the listner which take some time .....

add these line into your `onDataChange()` method and after end the `for loop` ................

```
  ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourClassName.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,friends);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

remove while condition .......................

enjoy coding.......................